# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter

Tags: struts2, struts, jakarta-migration

I'm using **Java SE-11, struts 2.5.29, tomcat 10.0.6** in my program.
I'm trying to create a small project using **struts-2 framework**.
I have declared all the filters in the `web.xml` as mentioned on the struts.apache.org for the particular version of Struts. Still I'm unable to execute my program successfully.
I think there is some error either in the jar files or something else which I'm not able to identify.

I have already tried older version of Struts 2.3.27 and even older version of tomcat9 but it didn't gave me the correct results.

Here is my `web.xml` and `struts.xml` code for reference.

**`web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
    <display-name>Strut2Implementation</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="welcome" class="org.action.WelcomeAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

the jars which I have added are

> commons-fileupload-1.4
> commons-io-2.6
> commons-lang3-3.8.1
> commons-lang-2.4
> commons-logging-1.2
> freemarker-2.3.30
> javassist-3.20.0
> ognl-3.1.29
> struts2-core-2.5.29
> struts-dwr-plugin-2.5.29
> xwork-core-2.2.3
> xwork-jar.jar

The error which I'm getting is

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts2] java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter

Comment: That error can’t occur in TC9.

Answer (score 1):

You use different servlet version on the   servlet container. This version is not backwards compatible with the version of Struts you have used.

See [Apache Tomcat Migration Gude](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html):

> There is a significant breaking change between Tomcat 9.0.x and Tomcat 10.0.x. The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from `javax...` to `jakarta...`. It will be necessary to recompile web applications against the new APIs.
>
> Tomcat can convert an existing web application from Java EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 at deployment time using the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE. To make use of the feature, the web application should be placed in the Host `legacyAppBase` folder (by default named `webapps-javaee`) and they will be converted to an equivalent Jakarta EE web application in the Host `appBase` folder (by default named `webapps`).
>
> Alternately, the [Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) or any similar conversion tool can be used ahead of time to benefit from faster deployment time and more precise conversion configuration options.