# 404 when I'm trying to use Servlet

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I just started learning Java Servlets. I do the tasks in accordance with the course I started, and it seems that everything is the same, but for some reason it does not work for me.

I'm trying to pass data from servlet to jsp page.

I have the following code:

`MvcServlet.java` :

```
package com.company.servletdemo;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "MvcServlet", urlPatterns = "/MvcServlet")

public class MvcServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String[] students = {"John", "Alex", "Michael"};
        request.setAttribute("student_list", students);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/mvcPage.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

And `mvcPage.jsp` :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<body>

<c:forEach var="tempStudent" items="${student_list}">

    ${tempStudent} <br/>

</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/servletdemo/MvcServlet` I have [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPBAl.png)

This is my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZNfg.png)

I saw few posts about problems with dispatcher problems, but they all hadn't "/" before path in `getRequestDispatcher()` while I have it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your app. It is not Jakarta. You should either update your libraries or use Tomcat 9.x for deployment.

For further reading see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71219592/573032) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
"/WEB-INF/mvcPage.jsp"
```

Comment: There's no file mvcPage.jsp in WEB-INF folder. So it'is absolute wrong path.

Comment: @RomanC  That's what the screenshot of the folder structure shows ...

Comment: There's no such path there. The file is in webapp.

Comment: @RomanC  Hmm.  Well there's an argument for not using screenshots in questions. Complete misinterpretation.

Comment: It's not a code posted as a screenshot. The answer is complete absurd.