# Getting Status: HTTP Status 404 after running Maven project on Eclipse and Tomcat " The requested resource is not available"

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am making a simple Maven Project using Eclipse. There is a form that has Username and Password and a submit button.
When I enter and submit the default username(admin) and password(admin). It should either show a page with "Pass" or "Fail" text if they match. But when I submit the form it shows [this error.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw6Rt.png). I am using Tomcat version 10.1 with javax servlet version 4.0.1 for this project and Eclipse EE edition.

[This is my file directory for the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipQi7.png)

I have installed the required dependency in the pom.xml file and got the servlet in the web.xml file as well. But I don't know why this issue is still there. I have tried other similar stack overflow solutions and from Google too but none of them worked so far.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginServlet" method="POST">
        <h1>JSP Page</h1>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Success.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% out.println("Pass"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% out.println("Fail"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package com.examSolution;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        
        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
            response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp");
        }else {
            response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my web.xml file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYPdG.png)

Comment: What is a goal of naming a project with the same name as servlet name?

Comment: @RomanC  So building the project again with different names helps, sir ?

Comment: How are you building and running this project?

Comment: @nitind Building using Run as Maven Build to generate the .war file and then Run as Run on Server on Tomcat v10.1 .

Comment: @AniketKajal The code is too old. You have to either update the code, or Run it on Server which is able to run it. For reference I can give you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77292951/573032) answer. It didn't help to anyone. May be it will help you.

Comment: Head to  *"javax.servlet doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer"* section in abovelinked duplicate for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering an HTTP 405 error, which typically means that the HTTP method used in the request is not supported by the target resource. In your case, it's likely because the servlet is not properly mapped in the web.xml file.

You're using servlet 3.0 annotation-based configuration, so you don't necessarily need entries in the web.xml file. However, if you're using an older version of Tomcat or prefer to configure servlets via web.xml, here's how you can configure it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
    <display-name>SimpleMavenProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.examSolution.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In this configuration:

- <servlet> tag defines your servlet class.
- <servlet-name> is a logical name for your servlet.
- <servlet-class> specifies the fully qualified class name of your servlet.
- <servlet-mapping> maps the servlet to a URL pattern.

Make sure that your web.xml file is correctly located in the WEB-INF directory of your web application.

If you're using servlet 3.0 or later, you can remove the servlet and servlet-mapping entries from the web.xml file altogether and rely solely on annotations like @WebServlet("/loginServlet") in your servlet class.

Also, ensure that your servlet class is properly compiled and included in the WAR file generated by Maven during the build process.

Comment: I am using Tomcat version 10.1 and Javax servlet version 4.0.1 dependency. I tried removing the unnecessary lines from web.xml and using @webservlet method but still it shows same error. Idk why its having a problem in Maven project. When I write the same in dynamic web project it works correctly. I am new to maven to i am baffled a bit

Comment: Uh, no, the question quite clearly says 404, not 405.