# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet in SpringMVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC, but I am stuck with this error for 2 days.

> "SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/SpringMVC] threw load() exception
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftUUf.png)

[spring-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P1Ok.png)

**`spring-servlet.xml` file:**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>com.learn.mvc</groupId>
      <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  

        <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->  
    <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
    <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
    </dependency>  
  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71208072/java-lang-classcastexception-class-org-apache-struts2-dispatcher-filter-strutsp)

Answer (score 0):

You have used old version of `servlet-api`. It's is not supported by your web server.

Update the server libraries:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>last</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also note if you have a legacy application which uses `javax.servlet` in the fependencies then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71219592/573032) answer might be helpful if you want to run it the new web server.

And if you choose to learn how to upgrade you application to the new API and run it on Spring Boot 3.0 then read [Spring Boot 3.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#Jakarta-EE).

> Whenever Spring Boot depends on a Jakarta EE specification, Spring Boot 3.0 has upgraded to the version that is included in Jakarta EE 10. For example, Spring Boot 3.0 uses the Servlet 6.0 and JPA 3.1 specifications.
>
> If you are managing your own dependencies, and aren’t relying on our starter POMs, you should ensure that you have updated your Maven or Gradle file appropriately. You need to be especially careful that older Java EE dependencies are no longer directly or transitively used in your build. For example, if you should always be using `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api` and not `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api`.
>
> As well as dependency coordinate changes, Jakarta EE now uses `jakarta` packages rather than `javax`. Once you’ve update your dependencies you may find that import statements in your project need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these dependencies instead

```
 <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Also, there is a useful video that covers how to set your Eclipse workspace and your project JDK and Tomcat.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fcn-r180vc8&ab_channel=MilosSesic

Please keep in mind that for Spring 5 you cannot use Tomcat 10, but Tomcat 9, due to the fact that Tomcat 9 and Spring 5 have packages with name `javax`, and Tomcat 10 and Spring 6 renamed them to `jakarta`. So if you are trying to use Tomcat 10 and Spring 6, these dependencies will not work and you will need to migrate all `javax` dependencies to `jakarta`.